# Dynamically change conda environment in reticulate

Tags: r, reticulate

Is it possible to dynamically change the conda environment through reticulate?

```
use_condaenv(condaenv='env1', conda='/path/to/conda')
package1 = import('pack1')
package1$do_smth

use_condaenv(condaenv='env2', conda='/path/to/conda')
package2 = import('pack2')
package2$do_smth2
```

Currently I get an import error here:

```
package2 = import('pack2')
```

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named pack2

Comment: Do you get an error when you pass `required = TRUE` to `use_condaenv`?

Comment: no error, but the environment does not change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're facing the problem because `reticulate` can **not** change python interpreter within a single R session. You get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named pack2` because `reticulate` is still using `env1` which doesn't have `pack2`. Try that:

```
use_condaenv(condaenv='env1', conda='/path/to/conda')
use_condaenv(condaenv='env2', conda='/path/to/conda', required = TRUE) # should throw an error
```

As a workaround, what you can do is to use `callr` package to run python code as if it would be running in a standalone R session:

```
library(callr)

# change variables accordindly:
venv <- "env2" # env1 or env2

# (optional) a python script containing a function which you would like to run from R
python_script_path <- "some_python_script.py"
# (optional)
some_other_parameter <- "foobar"

result <- r(function(venv, python_script_path, some_other_parameter){
    library(reticulate)
    use_condaenv(venv, conda='/path/to/conda', required = T)

    # try to import package
    package = import('pack2') # pack1 or pack2
    return(package$do_smth())

    # (oprional) or even to source a python script
    # source_python(python_script_path)
    # run a python function which is sourced from `python_script_path`
    # result <- run_calculations(some_other_parameter)
    # return(result)
  }, args = list(venv, python_script_path, some_other_parameter))
```

You should be able to run this code for `env1` with `pack1` and for `env2` with `pack2` within single session without a problem.

Note: the anonymous function will have it's own environment and in order to access variables from the global environment you need to pass them as parameters to the function (although probably you can pass the global environment itself, but I didn't try that).